# Inserting equation with Google Docs API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

Is it possible in Google Docs to insert Equation programatically with [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#equation)? The documentation is so confusing that I cannot figure out how to do it.

I also tried with [Google App Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/equation) library but with no luck either.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you’re trying to do. Include an image of the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Unfortunately so far programmaticaly you can only retrieve **already existing** equations and e.g. [copy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/equation#copy) them
- There is no endpoint to create new equations
- However, there is already a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36761273) for it on Google's Issue Tracker
- You can give it a "star" to increase visibility and show the importance of the feature

Comment: thank you, upvoted! I'm gonna make a chrome plugin for GDocs enhancement, but I suppose that manual DOM manipulation will lead to problems, am I right?

Comment: By plugin, do you mean a Chrome extension? Extensions are very useful for clientside manipulation of data, but I would not know how to write an extension that inserts a formula into Docs so that this equation will be recognized by Google Docs as such. If you find a way to do it - that would be well interesting!